How to Share High-Rate Data from LabVIEW to Other Programs on the Same Windows Machine?
I need to transfer data between two different programs. I have an embedded controller based on FPGA and Linux RT, which transmits data over network streams proprietary to National Instruments to a Windows-based host machine. I'm reading data through a program called LabVIEW, which is from National Instruments. I need to make this read data available for other programs running on the same  Windows machine.
I'm using network streams as they are tested and validated for high data rates and are easy to implement.
One method I am considering is to read the data through the LabVIEW program and then send it to the localhost of the same PC so that other programs can listen to the loopback address and get data.
Another method would be to pump data to a database and read data from other programs, but since I'm expecting data in the range of 100MB/s, I don't think a database is a good option.
I have two programs that need data: one is a Python code, and the second is a C++ code.
I heard there is a concept of shared memory, where I can post data from LabVIEW to shared memory and other programs could access it. I'm expecting guidance from experts here.
What is the best method to share high-rate data from LabVIEW to other programs on the same Windows machine? Specifically, how can I implement it effectively, considering my requirements? Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

There is a messaging library suitable for this task that is available for both LV and other languages: ZeroMQ - It supports network and IPC.
